# Amchart 5 disable interactive mode

Tags: angular, amcharts5

I would like to freeze my graph knowing that it is an XYCHART but unfortunately the forceInteractive does not work.

I tried to do step by step by disabling the cursor

```
if (this.displayNoData) {
  this.indicator.show();
  this.chart.set('forceInactive', true);
 } else {
  this.indicator.hide();
 }
```

I tried to do step by step by disabling the cursor